Object created via screw modifier exports empty
I'm just learning the Blender and I've made some progress about the UI,tools,etc. I was working on screw modifier and I've made an object with it.
I've started with a circle and than I've applied screw modifier and wield. and for the final result; Bevel and Subdivision Surface
Here's my result;


At Blender; everything seems good but when I export the model as STL; it seems weird and it's inner faces are visible;

Also in the Slicer program the result is same;

As a summary; my object doesn't behave like a solid object. Inside of it seems empty.
Not sure it's the right way to ask but; How can I fill inside of my object?

Maybe a manifold issue
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry

hello maybe make sure that the faces normals are correctly oriented, in Edit mode select all and Shift N?

thank you for your comments, I've tried Shift N but still same, I've also checked the non-manifold geometry but there's not any non-manifold geometry in my object (When I navigate to "Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold") there's nothing to selected. I'm still doing researches hope to finding a solution.

Hello mayb share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/
